# How to parse json data from json array to recyclerview java android?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I can parse json data to my recyclerview. but when i meet json that has array data in it, my app forceclose when i try to get that. How to solve this? or anyone has similar sample code with this case?

**Api:**

https://v1.nocodeapi.com/fariz/fit/FunuohzdbtxBkVtC/aggregatesDatasets?dataTypeName=steps_count,heart_minutes,weight,activity_summary

**Activity_Stepcounter.java**

```
Call<nodeApi> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getNode();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<nodeApi>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<nodeApi> call, Response<nodeApi> response) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                nodeApi resource = response.body();
                List<nodeApi.steps_count> dataList = resource.steps_count;

                Adapter_meeting rv_adapter = new Adapter_meeting(dataList, Activity_Stepcounter.this);
                rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Activity_Stepcounter.this));
                rv.setAdapter(rv_adapter);
                rv.hasFixedSize();
                rv_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<nodeApi> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
            }
        });
```

**Adapter_meeting.java**

```
public class Adapter_meeting extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_meeting.viewHolder> {
private final List<nodeApi.steps_count> mitem_meeting;
private final Context mContext;


public Adapter_meeting(List<nodeApi.steps_count> Item_meeting, Context mContext) {
    this.mitem_meeting = Item_meeting;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    }

@NonNull
@Override
public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view;
    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_step_counter, parent, false);
    final viewHolder vHolder = new viewHolder(view);
    return vHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tv_namaEvent.setText(mitem_meeting.get(position).getValue());
    holder.tv_lokasiEvent.setText(mitem_meeting.get(position).getStartTime());
    holder.tv_waktuEvent.setText(mitem_meeting.get(position).getEndTime());
    holder.tv_tanggalEvent.setText(mitem_meeting.get(position).getStartTimeMillis());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mitem_meeting.size();
}

public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView tv_namaEvent;
    private final TextView tv_lokasiEvent;
    private final TextView tv_waktuEvent;
    private final TextView tv_tanggalEvent;

    public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tv_namaEvent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_namaEvent);
        tv_lokasiEvent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_lokasiEvent);
        tv_waktuEvent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_waktuEvent);
        tv_tanggalEvent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_tanggalEvent);
    }
}}
```

**JsonPlaceHolderApi.java**

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {
   @GET("aggregatesDatasets?dataTypeName=steps_count,heart_minutes,weight,activity_summary")
Call<nodeApi> getNode();}
```

**nodeApi.java**

```
public class nodeApi {

    @SerializedName("steps_count")
    public List<steps_count> steps_count = null;

    public class steps_count {
        public Integer value;
        public String startTimeMillis;
        public String endTimeMillis;
        public String startTime;
        public String endTime;

        public steps_count(Integer value, String startTimeMillis, String endTimeMillis, String startTime, String endTime) {
            this.value = value;
            this.startTimeMillis = startTimeMillis;
            this.endTimeMillis = endTimeMillis;
            this.startTime = startTime;
            this.endTime = endTime;
        }

        public Integer getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(Integer value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getStartTimeMillis() {
            return startTimeMillis;
        }

        public void setStartTimeMillis(String startTimeMillis) {
            this.startTimeMillis = startTimeMillis;
        }

        public String getEndTimeMillis() {
            return endTimeMillis;
        }

        public void setEndTimeMillis(String endTimeMillis) {
            this.endTimeMillis = endTimeMillis;
        }

        public String getStartTime() {
            return startTime;
        }

        public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
            this.startTime = startTime;
        }

        public String getEndTime() {
            return endTime;
        }

        public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
            this.endTime = endTime;
        }
    }
}
```

**error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.iot.testapp, PID: 12849
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x19
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:335)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4555)
        at com.iot.testapp.adapter.Adapter_meeting.onBindViewHolder(Adapter_meeting.java:47)
        at com.iot.testapp.adapter.Adapter_meeting.onBindViewHolder(Adapter_meeting.java:26)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, i got help from discord

I have to make jsonresponse first and then convert it to arraylist using nodeApi.java.

```
public class JsonResponse {
    private nodeApi[] steps_count;

    public nodeApi[] getStep_count() {
        return steps_count;
    }

    public void setnodeApi(nodeApi[] step_count) {
        this.steps_count = step_count;
    }
}
```

**Activity_Stepcounter.java**

```
 Call<JsonResponse> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getStep();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonResponse> call, Response<JsonResponse> response) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                JsonResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                listStep = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getStep_count()));


                Adapter_meeting rv_adapter = new Adapter_meeting(listStep, Activity_Stepcounter.this);
                rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Activity_Stepcounter.this));
                rv.setAdapter(rv_adapter);
                rv.hasFixedSize();
                rv_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
            }
        });
```

**there are some refactor/rename.

Answer (score 0):

On these lines:

```
holder.tv_tanggalEvent.setText(mitem_meeting.get(position).getStartTimeMillis());
holder.tv_lokasiEvent.setText(mitem_meeting.get(position).getStartTime());
holder.tv_waktuEvent.setText(mitem_meeting.get(position).getEndTime());
```

Compilator thinks, that you are passing String resource, but you are actually passing simple String. Just add +"" and it should start working.

```
holder.tv_tanggalEvent.setText(mitem_meeting.get(position).getStartTimeMillis()+"");    
holder.tv_namaEvent.setText(mitem_meeting.get(position).getStartTime()+"");
holder.tv_waktuEvent.setText(mitem_meeting.get(position).getEndTime()+"");
```

You should pass text to textviews in form of String resource with placeholders, but it doesn't really make sense, when you don't pass there anything except the changing value.

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.tv_namaEvent.setText(mitem_meeting.get(position).getValue());
```

You are trying to set Int.
Try:

```
String value = String.valueOf(mitem_meeting.get(position).getValue());
holder.tv_namaEvent.setText(value);
```

Please check all fields for null and read about name convention in Android :)

Also time in milis should be stored in Long type.
You can also read about Kotlin language, mvvn pattern etc.